# Using map and passing object to subsequent function call

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have some code like so:

```
var downloadFiles = function () {
        console.log('downloading files');
        aFtpClient.
        listAsync().
        then(processListing).
        map(function (object) {
            return processItem(object);
        }).
        then(downloadItem).
        catch (TypeError, function (e) {
            console.dir('arse' + e);
        }).
        catch (Promise.RejectionError, function (e) {
            console.error("unable to read file, because: ", e.message);
        });
        console.log('after downloading files');
    };
```

`processListing` returns an array of objects with source & destination properties. I use `map` to deal with the array and call `processItem`. Is there a way to pass the mapped object to `downloadItem`?

Comment: You mean you want to access the `object` in `downloadItem`, not only the result of `processItem(object)`?

Comment: Yes as object contains the source ie/download from source and downloadItem to put to destination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with

```
.map(function (object) {
    return processItem(object).then(function(processResult) {
        return {input: object, result: processResult};
    });
})
```

Now `downloadItem` can access both `.input` and `.result` of each processed item.

Comment: Nice, it's worth mentioning that `.bind` can also be used to provide context to a promise chain in Bluebird which might be beneficial in cases like these.

Comment: Yeah, [`bind`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#binddynamic-thisarg---promise) can be helpful as well though I think it obscures the code a bit. Also, I don't think it works well with the `map`

Comment: Thanks, I was working on something similar to this today